# Split a row in a csv file into multiple rows using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, row

this is my first post on this website so please be gentle :) (Also a powershell noob)
I have received a .csv file and a .txt file. My job is to input data from the txt file into the csv file in the right rows.

I have managed to do that part.

[image: that is the output in the csv file.]

As you can see under the headline "Berechtigung" there is a number of roles separated by a ;
That was the information i had to include from the txt file in the csv file.

The last thing i need to do is separate the different roles with the help of ; and write them into the next row.

[image: I want this output]

Is this possible?

```
#dynamic variables
$password_Title = "Description" #Title of the password in the txt file (Description in pw7)
$row_Password = "Password" #row password in the txt file
$file_Path = "" #Path where the csv and txt file are located 
$txt_Content = "$file_Path\expensya.txt"  #Content of the txt file
$csv_File = "$file_Path\expensya.csv" #The CSV file which needs to be edited
$output_File_Path = "$file_Path\CSV-edited.csv" #Location and name of the of the new created csv file

$distance_row_title_pw = 4 #Distance between the row Description and password in the txt file
$distance_row_pw_Berechtigte = 8  #Distance between the row password and Berechtigte in the txt file 
$distance_row_Roles_description = 3 #Distance between the row Berechtigte and description in the txt file
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# static variables
$content = Get-Content -Path $txt_Content 
$csv_File = Import-Csv -Path $csv_File -Delimiter ';' -Encoding Default 
$password_Description = "" #In this variable the the row under description will be saved from the txt file
$password = "" #The password will be saved in this variable
$row_Berechtigte = "Berechtigte"  #Row named Berechtigte in the txt file
$csv_row = 1 

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


$csv_File | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Berechtigung" -Value $null 

#code execution

:forloop for($entry = 1; $entry -lt $content.Length; $entry++)
{
   if($content[$entry] -eq $password_title) 
   {
      $password_Description = $content[$entry+1]
      $entry = $entry + $distance_row_title_pw
   }  

   if ($content[$entry] -eq $row_Password)
   {
      $password = $content[$entry+1]
      $entry = $entry + $distance_row_pw_Berechtigte
   }

   if($content[$entry] -eq $row_Berechtigte) 
   {
   $csv_File| ForEach{if($_.$password_Title -eq $password_Description  -and $_.$row_Password-eq $password)
      {
         $csv_row = $csv_row +1
         if($_.Berechtigung -eq $null)
         {
            $roles = $content[$entry+1]
            $_.Berechtigung = $roles
            $entry = $entry + $distance_row_Roles_description
            continue forloop
         }
         elseif ($_.$password_Title -eq $password_Description  -and $_.$row_Password-eq $password -and $_.Berechtigung -eq $content[$entry+1]) 
         {
            Write-Host "Fehler bei diesem Eintrag $password_Description in Zeile $csv_row. Identical Values!"
            $csv_File | Export-Csv -Path $output_File_Path  -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation | % {$_.Berechtigung -replace '"', ''}
            break
         }
      }
      }
   }
   
}

$csv_File | Export-Csv -Path $output_File_Path -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

this is the csv file

```
Organisationseinheit;Description;Username;Password;Internetaddress;EMail-Address
Expensya;Expensya API Subscription Key - Secondary;;10;;
Expensya;Expensya API Subscription Key - Primary;;20;;
Expensya;Expensya API Token - Projects;;30;;
Expensya;Expensya API Token - HR;;40;;
Expensya;Expensya API Token - SAP;;50;;
Expensya;Expensya API Subscription Key - Secondary;;10;;
```

and this is the txt file:

```
Password (v7): Expensya API Subscription Key - Primary (Expensya)
Description
Expensya API Subscription Key - Primary
Username

Password
20
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
07.12.2021 14:24:23
Berechtigte
Administrator (Administrator); Administrators; Role_ApplMan_Technisch_-_Expensya
 
Password (v7): Expensya API Subscription Key - Secondary (Expensya)
Description
Expensya API Subscription Key - Secondary
Username

Password
10
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
09.12.2021 13:43:00
Berechtigte
Administrator (Administrator); Administrators; Role_ApplMan_Technisch_-_Expensya
 
Password (v7): Expensya API Token - HR (Expensya)
Description
Expensya API Token - HR
Username

Password
40
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
07.12.2021 14:22:38
Berechtigte
Administrator (Administrator); Administrators; Role_ApplMan_Technisch_-_Expensya
 
Password (v7): Expensya API Token - Projects (Expensya)
Description
Expensya API Token - Projects
Username

Password
30
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
07.12.2021 14:22:59
Berechtigte
Administrator (Administrator); Administrators; Role_ApplMan_Technisch_-_Expensya
 
Password (v7): Expensya API Token - SAP (Expensya)
Description
Expensya API Token - SAP
Username

Password
50
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
07.12.2021 14:21:59
Berechtigte
Administrator (Administrator); Administrators; Role_ApplMan_Technisch_-_Expensya
 
Password (v7): Expensya SSO Secret (App Registration) (Expensya)
Description
Expensya API Subscription Key - Secondary
Username
-
Password
10
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
07.12.2021 16:23:11
Berechtigte
Administrator (Administrator); Administrators; Role_ApplMan_Technisch_-_Expensya
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of the images of the data you should share - at least for the input sample data - the plain text formatted as code. This way we could copy that and use it to reproduce your situation. ;-)

Comment: how many Berechtigung semi-colon delimited can there be? Is it always a fixed value (3)? For future reference, please always share CSV as plain text to your question instead of screenshots

Comment: CSV is generally a "fixed-width" format, you can't just tack an arbitrary number of cells behind the last column.

Comment: hello @SantiagoSquarzon , in this case there are three, but on other cases it may be more.

Comment: Hello @Olaf i am not sure what you mean by this. Could you perhaps elaborate further?

Comment: The goal is essentially to take a few lines from the txt file which contain the roles and add them to the csv file under the column berechtigung. Thats something i have already managed to do. Last thing to implement now is to split the row of the roles who are divided by ; and seperate them into the other row.

Comment: OK, but then you did not share the proper sample data. You may share the CSV data with the concatenated column for "Berechtigungen". Depending on what you want to do with the data it might be an option to split the column only when you use it. This way you read it as one column and treat it with a nested loop if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since your sample data in your *text file* is quite limitted and does not contain a lot of different sets of *Berechtigungen* I chnaged it slightly to be able to show how to parse plain text files with `ConvertFrom-String`.

Here are the modified input data I saved as `D:\sample\input.log`

```
Password (v7): Expensya API Subscription Key - Primary (Expensya)
Description
Expensya API Subscription Key - Primary
Username

Password
20
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
07.12.2021 14:24:23
Berechtigte
Administrator (Administrator); Friedjoff; Role_ApplMan_Technisch_-_Expensya

Password (v7): Expensya API Subscription Key - Secondary (Expensya)
Description
Expensya API Subscription Key - Secondary
Username

Password
10
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
09.12.2021 13:43:00
Berechtigte
Administrator (Administrator); Egon; Role_ApplMan_Analog_-_Expensya
 
Password (v7): Expensya API Token - HR (Expensya)
Description
Expensya API Token - HR
Username

Password
40
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
07.12.2021 14:22:38
Berechtigte
Administrator (Administrator); Bernd; Role_ApplMan_Organisatorisch_-_Expensya
 
Password (v7): Expensya API Token - Projects (Expensya)
Description
Expensya API Token - Projects
Username

Password
30
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
07.12.2021 14:22:59
Berechtigte
Administrator (Administrator); Fritz; Role_ApplMan_Magisch_-_Expensya
 
Password (v7): Expensya API Token - SAP (Expensya)
Description
Expensya API Token - SAP
Username

Password
50
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
07.12.2021 14:21:59
Berechtigte
Administrator (Administrator); Hans; Role_ApplMan_Bla_-_Expensya
 
Password (v7): Expensya SSO Secret (App Registration) (Expensya)
Description
Expensya API Subscription Key - Secondary
Username
-
Password
10
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
07.12.2021 16:23:11
Berechtigte
Administrator (Administrator); Rudi; Role_ApplMan_Keks_-_Expensya
```

Now I created a template using curly braces and labels to specify the desired values:

```
$Template = 
@'
Password (v7): Expensya API Subscription Key - Primary ({Orga*:Expensya})
Description
Expensya API {Description:Subscription Key - Primary}
Username

Password
{Password:20}
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
07.12.2021 14:24:23
Berechtigte
{Berechtigung:Administrator (Administrator); Friedjoff; Role_ApplMan_Organisatorisch_-_Expensya}
 
Password (v7): Expensya API Subscription Key - Secondary ({Orga*:Expensya})
Description
Expensya API {Description:Subscription Key - Secondary}
Username

Password
{Password:10}
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
09.12.2021 13:43:00
Berechtigte
{Berechtigung:Administrator (Administrator); Hans; Role_ApplMan_Analog_-_Expensya}
 
Password (v7): Expensya API Token - HR ({Orga*:Expensya})
Description
Expensya API {Description:Token - HR}
Username

Password
{Password:40}
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
07.12.2021 14:22:38
Berechtigte
{Berechtigung:Administrator (Administrator); Franz; Role_ApplMan_Theoretisch_-_Expensya}
 
Password (v7): Expensya API Token - Projects ({Orga*:Expensya})
Description
Expensya API {Description:Token - Projects}
Username

Password
{Password:30}
Internetaddress

EMail-Address

Letzte Änderung
07.12.2021 14:22:59
Berechtigte
{Berechtigung:Administrator (Administrator); Kunz; Role_ApplMan_Technisch_-_Expensya}
'@
```

And at last I used `ConvertFrom-String` with the 4 examples to extract the desired data:

```
Get-Content -Path 'D:\sample\input.log' | 
    ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $Template
```

The output looks like this:

```
Orga     Description                  Password Berechtigung
----     -----------                  -------- ------------
Expensya Subscription Key - Primary   20       Administrator (Administrator); Friedjoff; Role_ApplMan_Technisch_-_Expensya
Expensya Subscription Key - Secondary 10       Administrator (Administrator); Egon; Role_ApplMan_Analog_-_Expensya
Expensya Token - HR                   40       Administrator (Administrator); Bernd; Role_ApplMan_Organisatorisch_-_Expensya
Expensya Token - Projects             30       Administrator (Administrator); Fritz; Role_ApplMan_Magisch_-_Expensya
Expensya Token - SAP                  50       Administrator (Administrator); Hans; Role_ApplMan_Bla_-_Expensya
Expensya Subscription Key - Secondary 10       Administrator (Administrator); Rudi; Role_ApplMan_Keks_-_Expensya
```

Here you can learn how to use `ConvertFrom-String` to parse plain text
[Sophisitcated Techniques of Plain Text Parsing](https://youtu.be/Hkzd8spCfCU?t=1394)

Comment: thats awesome! Can you show me how you build your template?

Comment: I added a link to the video where Tobias explains it. He's way better than me explaining stuff. ;-)

Comment: i see. So in order for this to work you will always have to modify the txt file. (Adding the curly braces)

Comment: No. You use a representative excerpt from the original as a template to train PowerShell. Did you see the video? Additionally you should read the help [ConvertFrom-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string?view=powershell-5.1)